# Install MongoDB on Debian

Tags: mongodb, installation, mongodb-3.0, debian

I tried to install MongoDB using this command:

```
apt-get install mongodb=3.0.1
```

But the version 3.0.1 was not found.

How can I install it?

Comment: tried `apt-get update` before executing `apt-get install mongodb=3.0.1` ? Or check out https://github.com/dolonfly/book-library/blob/master/doc/apt-get-latest-mongodb.md

Answer (score 1):

To install specific version of mongodb you need to follow certain steps documented on MongoDB site:

In my opinion it includes:

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=3.0.1 mongodb-org-server=3.0.1 mongodb-org-shell=3.0.1 mongodb-org-mongos=3.0.1 mongodb-org-tools=3.0.1
```

You can opt for packages by omitting it from above list.

You can find detailed document [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/)